# Get count of complex query

Tags: mysql, select, join, count, having

I would like to count the total number of rows returned by the following query:

```
SELECT table1.*, COUNT(table2.fk) * (100/18) AS 'number' 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.pk = table2.fk
WHERE table1.Street LIKE '$Street%' 
AND table1.City LIKE '$City%' 
AND table1.Zip LIKE '%$Zip' 
AND table1.DOBY LIKE '%$DOBY' 
AND table1.DOBM LIKE '%$DOBM' 
AND table1.DOBD LIKE '%$DOBD' 
AND table1.Gender LIKE '$gender%' 
AND table2.year>= 2004 
AND table2.type IN ('AA', 'AB', 'AC') 
GROUP BY table2.fk
HAVING (COUNT(table2.fk) * (100/18)) >= '$activity' 
ORDER BY DOBY, DOBM, DOBD ASC
```

The query counts the number or times the primary key of table1 occurs as the foreign key of table2, and calculates a percentage ('number') based on a fixed amount. It works well enough, but I'm having trouble getting the total amount of records found for my pagination script.
I would appreciate it if anyone can offer some suggestions or solutions.

Comment: Would doing a subquery work (i.e., `(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE conditional = $variable) AS count`)? Or is this query what you need the count for? I don't see the `LIMIT` keyword.

Comment: This is the query that I need the count for. It is much more complex, but I edited it down a bit for the sake of simplicity. The limit keyword comes after the last line, "LIMIT $start, $limit;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can do `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` (google for exact syntax)
And then use `SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS total`

Comment: Much thanks! It's a bit slow on the very large database I'm using, but it will have to work for now.

Comment: If it is very big, you should cache the count. No one give exact numbers (not event Google) in their paginations for really large numbers. And one more thing, yuo use this ONLY at the first time, you should definitely cache it for small time intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Going with what Itay Moav says, a programming language should have a function for the `found_rows` function. As per the [function documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows), it returns the number of rows of a `SELECT` statement with a `LIMIT` keyword if the `LIMIT` keyword wasn't there.

If it doesn't, you can just make another `SELECT` query to the database: `SELECT FOUND_ROWS();`. It will return the same information.